# Label animation on data change

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change to background color animation of a label based on the value of an integer.

```
MyInt = 1 then label1.background color = Red

MyInt = 2 then label1.background color = Green

MyInt = 3 then label1.background color = Yellow
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction as I’m completely new to **WPF**. 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7)s to change properties based on a bound value. The easiest way would be to add a style to your label.

Comment: Another way is ValueConverter